# C# XML Serialization Attribute before class declaration

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, dto

I have this class

```
public class dtoObject : CommonBase
{
    [XmlArray("SomeItems"), XmlArrayItem("SomeItem")]
    public List<dtoSomeItem> SomeItems
    {
        get { return _SomeItems; }
        set { _SomeItems = value; }
    }
 }
```

and I would would like to use XML Serialization to make the XML string appear to be:

```
<Objects>
    <Object>
        <SomeItems>
            <SomeItem>
              1
            </SomeItem>
            <SomeItem>
              2
            </SomeItem>
        </SomeItems>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <SomeItems>
            <SomeItem>
              3
            </SomeItem>
            <SomeItem>
              4
            </SomeItem>
        </SomeItems>
    </Object>
</Objects>
```

But for the life of me I cant figure out what to put before

```
public class dtoObject
```

in terms of Attributes, so that I get

```
<Objects><Object>...</Object><Object>...
```

when I serialize this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I got to work. Thanks to comptent_tech and dthorpe for their help. I created my DTO like so:

```
[XmlType("Object", Namespace = "", TypeName = "Object")]
public class dtoObject : CommonBase   
{       
    [XmlArray("SomeItems"), XmlArrayItem("SomeItem")]       
    public List<dtoSomeItem> SomeItems       
    {
        get { return _SomeItems; }           
        set { _SomeItems = value; }       
    }    
}
```

My function that does the serializing is this:

```
public string ToXML(List<dtoObject> oObject)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(oObject.GetType(), new XmlRootAttribute("Objects"));
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");

    using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
    {

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, oObject, ns);

        xmlStream.Position = 0;
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
        return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
    }
}
```

Doing this creates the xml format of:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Objects>
        <Object>
            <SomeItems>
                <SomeItem>
                </SomeItem>
            </SomeItems>
        </Object>
    <Objects>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do this with your object structure because the XML effectively declares a wrapper around the SomeItems collection. For example:

```
[XmlType("Objects")]
public class dtoObject : CommonBase
{
    [XmlElement("Object")]
    public List<dtoSomeItemWrapper> SomeItemsWrappers
    {
        get { return _SomeItemsWrappers; }
        set { _SomeItemsWrappers = value; }
    }
 }

class dtoSomeItemWrapper
{
    [XmlArray("SomeItems"), XmlArrayItem("SomeItem")]
    public List<dtoSomeItem> SomeItems
    {
        get { return _SomeItems; }
        set { _SomeItems = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: comptent_tech I appreciate the reply, but the xml string that gets generated is like this `<?xml version="1.0"?><ArrayOfDtoObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><dtoObject><SomeItems><SomeItem></SomeItem></SomeItems></dtoObject><dtoObject><SomeItems /></dtoObject><dtoObject><SomeItems><SomeItem></SomeItem><SomeItem></SomeItem></SomeItems></dtoObject></ArrayOfDtoObject>`

Comment: @user1066353: Ok, updated the answer so that it should generate exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like `XmlRootAttribute("Object", Namespace="", IsNullable=false)` in front of the class declaration. That tells the XML serializer to use the `<Object>` tag to represent the dtoObject in the XML text.

As for the `<Objects>` tag, you won't get that unless you are serializing an array of dtoObject. That is beyond the scope of the dtoObject type.

Comment: dthorpe, thank you for the reply but when I add the Attribute like you suggested to my dtoObject class, the xml gets written to a string like this:  <?xml version="1.0"?><ArrayOfDtoObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><dtoObject>...

Comment: How are you serializing the object to xml?  Are you using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Save()?

Comment: I'm passing a `List<dtoObject>` to this function `public string ToXML(Object oObject) { XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(oObject.GetType()); using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream()) { xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, oObject); xmlStream.Position = 0; xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream); return xmlDoc.InnerXml; } }`